# Can't make DynamoDb Java SDK NameMap. "Identifier expected but 'with' found"

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to make a dynamoDB query in scala using Amazon's DynamoDB SDK.

For some reason it's not accepting the `.with` function. The compiler gives the following error:

"Error:(33, 8) identifier expected but 'with' found.
      .with("#hash", "hash value")"

it's definitely a method in the NameMap. Why is it not compiling?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Scala uses `with` as a keyword. This would mess up the syntax and give that error. Luckily there's a way in scala to escape the keyword using backticks.

```
new NameMap()
.`with`("#hash", "hash value")
```